# Confusion in the dbutils.fs.ls() command output. Please suggest

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

When I use the below command in Azure Databricks

`display(dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/MLRExtract/excel_v1.xlsx"))`

My output is coming as `wasbs://paycnt@sdvstr01.blob.core.windows.net/mnt/MLRExtract/excel_v1.xlsx`

not as expected-- `dbfs://mnt/MLRExtract/excel_v1.xlsx`

Please suggest

Comment: It is because you're using mount point location. Think of it as an alias to your blob storage.

Comment: @DKNY ,  How should I do that? Could u pls suggest me.

Comment: Did you configure your cluster with the blob storage details?

Comment: @DKNY , I'm beginner in Azure. Used this below code to mount -- ```dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = f"wasbs://{blob.storage_account_container}@{blob.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/",

  mount_point = "/mnt/MLRExtract/",

  extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.{blob.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net":blob.storage_account_access_key})``` Is there anything I'm missing

Comment: See [this microsoft documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#spark-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Mounting a storage account to Databricks File System allows users to access them any number of times without any credentials. Any files or directories can be accessed from Databricks clusters using these mount points. The procedure you used allows you to mount blob storage container to DBFS.

So, you can access your blob storage container from DBFS using the mount point. The method `dbutils.fs.ls(<mount_point>)`  displays all the files and directories available in that mount point. It is not necessary to provide path of a file, instead simply use:

```
display(dbutils.fs.ls(“/mnt/MLRExtract/”))
```

The above command returns all the files available in the mount point (which is your blob storage container). You can perform all the required operations and then write to this DBFS, which will be reflected in your blob storage container too.

Refer to the following link to understand more about Databricks file system.

https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html

Comment: Hey @kanishkkashyap, has it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?